# Task for interview that is simple yet shows knowledge about WPF and MVVM

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

Today I'll be interviewing WPF developers and I want to give them some task that is simple yet gives them opportunity to show how they can write code. The most important thing I want to know is how person understands MVVM pattern. Also it's nice to see if they understand threading, databinding, themes. Can you suggest such a task?

Comment: If you are not able to think of such a task, do you qualify to assess the developers?

Comment: @Erno You want him to hire someone that can assess the developer? :P

Comment: @Fuji - not necessarily. I just dislike interviewers who don't know what they are talking about. If you can't make up the question, how are you going to evaluate the answer? (Yes, I get hired to assess candidates :) )

Comment: Haha, yea I understand your point and I agree fully, but it's a tricky situation. ;)

Comment: Well what else should I do if I want ho hire a developer better than myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter what the task is. What matters is the skills demonstrated.

So pick any small simple app, and tell them that you want them to build it using the MVVM design pattern, and to demonstrate threading, databinding, and themes within the project.

The app doesn't even have to have a realistic purpose. It could be as simple as

> Create a 2-screen application using the MVVM design pattern, with one
>   page containing a dropdown of themes to select, and the other page
>   containing a TextBox that loads the Text on a background thread after
>   a short delay

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to make them write code to check their understanding of MVVM, you can simply give them a scenario and ask them to define what views, ViewModels and Models they will define to build this application. Simply discussing their design will give you enough idea about their knowledge of MVVM.

As a candidate I would never prefer to build a working application withing an hour or so (using WPF, MVVM, Commands, Threading etc.) irrespective of the task;

When it comes to coding tasks, What I have found best is that HR send(mail) me the well defined problem at my preferred time and specify the time limit, after which I need to send them the working solution; and later a technical guy having a round of interview based on my solution, discussing the things I have done and why I did something like this etc. (this way you can always find out genuineness of the solution).

In past I have come across this kind of interviews and it was a very good opportunity to showcase my knowledge and skills.

Some of the tasks you can give -

1. Build a calculator using MVVM and WPF; Implement simple operations like Addition etc. and make the UI flexible.

   You can increase the number and complexity of operations to implement depending on time limit(like log, mod, factorial etc.)

   You can also specify that a particular operation (e.g. factorial of a number) should be performed asynchronously (using background worker, threading etc.).
2. Creating a simple trading monitor, where user can add new stocks and a list of stocks will be displayed in grid like structure; simulate the way to change the stock price randomly and highlight the price cell depending type of change(increment/decrement)

For both tasks specify that you need to use WPF features like xaml, binding, commands, templates, styles, triggers as much as possible.

You can find a lot of such tasks on net; but whatever the problem, key is to have the well defined task, specifying your expectations and providing candidate sufficient time & comfortable environment. And of course the review discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Nice MVVM stuff - switchable Views and ViewModels using DataTemplateSelector.

For instance you have following:

1. type Point:

```cs
public class Point
{
   public Point(int x, int y)
   {  
      this.X = x;
      this.Y = y;
   }

   public int X { get; private set; }
   public int Y { get; private set; }
}
```

1. Set of points
2. Single main Window

You need to design application which would generate different set of points in run time using random generator and each N-seconds push new data set to UI, UI should not freeze up event using large data set. Application User should be able switching between different data representations by a button click: Grid View, Line Chart view.

- Grid View basically display point per row with two columns X and Y
- Line Chart View display trend line

Answer (score 0):

I always wondered why people tend to give people tasks? Usually it is enough to ask some questions, poke here a bit and there a bit and you will find much more about the knowledge level of the person in front of you. Anyway

- Ask him about different ways to supply an item template to an
  ItemsControl.
- Let him tell you what he knows about the Dispatcher. Ask how he would
  handle collection of models inside a model and how the view model
  would look. If you strongly stick to MVVM.

  class Model
  {
      public ObservableCollection Children{get;set;}
  }
- Ask him whats the difference between an UserControl and a
  CustomControl.
- Difference between StaticResource and DynamicResource
- How he would handle selections, multiple selections and commands
  acting on this selection

I know you asked for a specific task, which i think is difficult to define, it depends on what you want from the programmer. But maybe these points give you some idea to form a task, or you just use them to ask him about stuff like i meant earlier.

Comment: dowhilefor, I agree; interviews are suffcient to find the knowledge level of a person; but sometimes as a candidate coding exercise gives you a window to showcase your knowledge and skills, which an interviewer might not be able to find out. In an i/w interviewer asks what he wants to know, but in coding exercise candidate (can) shows what he knows and is best in.

Answer (score 0):

Why not get them to write a financial Stock monitoring app. Give them the url of the Yahoo finance api (allowing you to get stock data in real time), then they could write an app to consume and display real-time data

MVVM - that could be a prerequisite

DataBinding - bind to stock data

Threading - get data ticks on background thread

Themes - why not

However, you run the risk of hiring someone who has read a lot of books but doesnt have a lot of pragmatic experience getting the job done. Much better to get you own hotest dev to give them a thoroughly good grilling :)